# How to find the source of a copied file?

Tags: linux, unix, cp, xterm

I have a file that I copied sometime back, but I forgot the source of it. Is there a way to find the source of the copied file? I don't remember which terminal I have used to try and check with Esc+P

Command used: cp -rf $source/file $destination/file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `history` command maybe help?

Answer (score 2):

A Linux system has many files (and if you think of `/proc/`, it could change at every moment). And some *other* process can write or create (or append or truncate) files (e.g. some [crontab(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) job...)

Assume you do know some parent directory containing the source file. Suppose it is `/home/foo`.

Then, you might use [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and some hashing command like [md5sum(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html) to compute and collect the hash of every file.

Use the property that two files *A* and *B* with identical contents (a sequence of bytes) have the same `md5sum`. Of course, the converse is false, but in practice unlikely.

So run first

```
find /home/foo -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; > /tmp/foo-md5
```

then do `seekingmd5=$(md5sum` *A* `)`

then `grep $seekingmd5 /tmp/foo-md5` will find lines for files having the same `md5` than your original *A*

Depending on your filesystem and hardware, this could take hours.

You could accelerate *slightly* things by writing a C program using [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) with `md5init` etc...

Comment: You could probably speed this up a lot by only searching for files that are the exact same size as the target. For example, if the target file contains 12,345 bytes, add `-size 12345c` to the command line options for `find`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `history | grep your_filename`.

Comment: What is `>` ? If it's a prompt my advice is to remove it from the command — it confuses reader as they think they must type the character themselves and then they get errors.

Comment: Edited. I'm not sure about this, but in cases like this it's the right thing to side with the most conservative view :)